# Generating floating point limits at compile time via template arguments and constexpr semantics:

Tags: c++, templates, floating-point, c++17, compile-time-constant

I'm working on a set of classes. My `Function` class will take a `Functor` class which stores a `function pointer` to some defined function which has an operator that will invoke the function call from the function pointer. It uses a `Limit` class that currently takes `<int,int>` for its upper and lower bounds. It has nothing but `static constexpr` functions to return the bounds and to calculate the number of elements between those bounds. If the lower bounds = 1 and upper bounds = 5 it will generate 5 for the number of elements to be evaluated for that function...

Here is what I'm doing with these classes:

- First I declare a function such as f(x) = x, f(x) = x^2, or f(x) = cos(x), etc.
- Then I instantiate a `Functor` object based on the above function(s) parameter types both for the return and for its parameter-argument types...
- Next, I assign the function to my `Functor` class's member variable.
- Then I instantiate a `Function` object giving it the `data-type` and the `Lower` & `Upper` limits for the range of the function.
- The `Function` class upon construction automatically generates the data points of that function from `[lower,upper]` and stores the generated values in its internal array.
- The `Function` class also contains an `operator` that will allow the user to get any value from any given input.

**Pseudo Example:**

```
f(x) = x^2;

Functor<T,T> functor;
functor.member = &f(x);
Function<T,Lower,Upper,T> function(functor); 

// If T=int, Lower = -4, and Upper = 4 then the internal data set will be 
// (-4,16) (-3,9), (-2,4), (-1,1), (0,0), (1,1), (2,4), (3,9), (4,16)
// The user can also use it's operator to call function(9) and it will return 81
```

---

Here is my working program that is generating datasets of values from my classes using various functions:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <cmath>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

#include "Function.h"

int main() {
    try {
        pipes::Functor<int, int> functor1;
        functor1.FuncPtr = &square;
        pipes::Function<int, -10, 10, int> func1( functor1 );
        auto data1{ func1.data() };
        for (auto& p : data1)
            std::cout << '(' << p.first << ',' << p.second << ")\n";
        std::cout << '\n';
        std::cout << "f(25) = " << func1(25) << "\n\n";

        pipes::Functor<int, int> functor2;
        functor2.FuncPtr = &linear;
        pipes::Function<int, -10, 10, int> func2(functor2);
        auto data2{ func2.data() };
        for (auto& p : data2)
            std::cout << '(' << p.first << ',' << p.second << ")\n";
        std::cout << '\n';
        std::cout << "f(25) = " << func2(25) << "\n\n";

        pipes::Functor<double, double> functor3;
        functor3.FuncPtr = &cosine;
        pipes::Function<double, -7, 7, double> func3(functor3);
        auto data3{ func3.data() };
        for (auto& p : data3)
            std::cout << '(' << p.first << ',' << p.second << ")\n";
        std::cout << '\n';
        std::cout << "f(25) = " << func3(25) << "\n\n";

    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << "\n\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Function.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <array>

namespace pipes {

    template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
    struct Functor {
        Ret(*FuncPtr)(Args...);
        Ret operator()(Args... args) { return FuncPtr(args...); }
    };

    template<int Lower, int Upper>
    class Limits {
    public:
        static constexpr unsigned lower_bound() { return Lower; }
        static constexpr unsigned upper_bound() { return Upper; }
        static constexpr unsigned element_count() { return (Upper - Lower + 1); }
    };

    template<typename T, int Lower, int Upper, typename... Args>
    class Function {        
        std::array<std::pair<T, T>, Limits<Lower,Upper>::element_count()> data_points_;
        Functor<T,Args...> functor_;
    public:
        Function(Functor<T,Args...> func) {
            functor_ = func;
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < Limits<Lower,Upper>::element_count(); i++) {
                data_points_[i].first = ((T)i + (T)Lower);
                data_points_[i].second = functor_(data_points_[i].first);
            }
        }

        T operator()(Args... args) const { 
            return functor_.FuncPtr(args...);
        }

        constexpr auto lower() const { return Lower; }
        constexpr auto upper() const { return Upper; }
        constexpr auto count() const { return Limits<Lower,Upper>::element_count(); }
        constexpr auto data() const { return data_points_; }
    };

} // namespace pipes
```

When I run the program it is generating this output which appears to be correct:

**Output**

```
(-10,100)
(-9,81)
(-8,64)
(-7,49)
(-6,36)
(-5,25)
(-4,16)
(-3,9)
(-2,4)
(-1,1)
(0,0)
(1,1)
(2,4)
(3,9)
(4,16)
(5,25)
(6,36)
(7,49)
(8,64)
(9,81)
(10,100)

f(25) = 625

(-10,-10)
(-9,-9)
(-8,-8)
(-7,-7)
(-6,-6)
(-5,-5)
(-4,-4)
(-3,-3)
(-2,-2)
(-1,-1)
(0,0)
(1,1)
(2,2)
(3,3)
(4,4)
(5,5)
(6,6)
(7,7)
(8,8)
(9,9)
(10,10)

f(25) = 25

(-7,0.753902)
(-6,0.96017)
(-5,0.283662)
(-4,-0.653644)
(-3,-0.989992)
(-2,-0.416147)
(-1,0.540302)
(0,1)
(1,0.540302)
(2,-0.416147)
(3,-0.989992)
(4,-0.653644)
(5,0.283662)
(6,0.96017)
(7,0.753902)

f(25) = 0.991203
```

---

And now for my question where this becomes the tricky part...

With my code currently the way it is, everything is fine as long as my bounds `[-a,b]` are of an `integral` type...

Let's suppose on my last example such as with `cos`, what if I want to have my bounds from `[-2pi,2pi]` where the lower and upper limits are of floating-point types...

**The Issue:**

Currently in C++ this is non-standard and in most cases won't compile:

```
template<float val> // or template<double>
struct foo() {
    constexpr float operator()() {
        return val;
    }
};
```

And the above prevents me from doing something like this:

```
constexpr double PI{ 6.28318531 };

pipes::Functor<double, double> functor3;
functor3.FuncPtr = &cosine;
pipes::Function<double, -PI, PI, double> func3(functor3);
auto data3{ func3.data() };
for (auto& p : data3)
    std::cout << '(' << p.first << ',' << p.second << ")\n";
std::cout << '\n';
std::cout << "f(25) = " << func3(25) << "\n\n";
```

So if I want to be able to support floating-point types for my `intervals` of my `Limits` or `Range` class... What kind of alternative would there be if such a thing is currently possible in c++? Or would I just have to simply restructure the way my class templates are designed?

If the above is possible in some way during compile time via templates and constexpr semantics, then there is another issue that arises that will have to be taken into consideration and that would be the stepping interval for use with floating-point types to know how many data points there will be within the dataset... (basically calculating `dx` based on some stepping value which would be defined by the user, for example: (0.1, 0.001, etc...) and the number of data points would be calculated by the number of these divisions between [lower, upper]... However, if the stepping value is known at compile-time, then calculating the divisions should be simple enough... that's not a major concern. The bigger concern is being able to express floating-point constants at compile time for template evaluation...

Currently, with the way my code is with its design, I have hit a limit on its functionality... I'm not sure how to provide a similar interface to support a `floating-point` range that can be calculated and generated at compile time! Any bit of help or suggestions is welcomed!

Comment: Currently, it would only work if you designate an own type for each floating-point range like `struct pi_range { constexpr double lower =  -IP , constexpr double upper =  IP};` (or for each lower and upper individually) and using `pi_range` like as argument: `pipes::Function<double, pi_range, double>`

Comment: @t.niese I kind of understand what you are getting at, however, I don't want to have to explicitly create multiple structs for different ranges, I want to be able to "generalize" it!

Comment: With `consteval`  it probably might be possible but I didn't check that yet (especially because it is c++20) but as long as the value is in some way required to identify the template it is imho not possible. So even a `pipes::Function<double, range(-1.0,1.0), double>` won't work because there the arguments `-1.0` and `1.0` are part of the identification of the template. You don't need to have struct for the range, you could also only have an individual struct for the lower and upper part.

Comment: @t.niese I'm trying some alternatives right now, I'm getting close, however, it is forcing me to use `std::vector` instead of `std::array`. I was trying to use `array` for small sample sizes to be stack and cache-friendly, but having to know the size ahead of time is what's making it difficult. With the use of `vector` instead, I don't need to know its size and can calculate that in the constructor of `Function`, which I do have a working example, however, the `x` part of the `f(x)` for the `floating point function` isn't giving me the correct values. It might be due to casting and truncation.

Comment: @t.niese you can check out my answer for my modified version that will allow for `floating-point` limits, except it can't be done at compile-time, but can be achieved during run-time... maybe one day, C++ will support floating-point-compile-time-constants as template-arguments...

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest you can get to a construct like yours is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

constexpr const double PI_2{ 6.28318531 };

template<double const &lower, double const &upper>
void foo() {
    static_assert(lower<upper, "invalid lower and upper value");
    
    constexpr size_t size = (upper-lower);
    std::array<int, size> test;
    
    std::cout << lower << " " << upper << " " << test.size() << std::endl;
}

template<double const &V>
struct neg {
  static constexpr double value = -V;
};

int main()
{
    foo<neg<PI_2>::value, PI_2>();
    
    return 0;
}
```

If you can always specify the type as first template argument you could have something like this:

```
template<typename T, T const &lower, T const &upper>
void foo() {
    std::cout << lower << " " << upper << std::endl;
}
```

I didn't fully think it through, how to get the floating-point part and the other together, but I think it should be possible.

Comment: Nice proposal. I understand why C++ doesn't currently support floating-point constants as template arguments. It's because floating-point implementations aren't standard from one machine or OS to the next... If every machine implements IEE-754, then yes it would be possible for C++ to support it, however, that's not the case and because of that, a compile-time floating constant on one machine may not be interpreted the same on another... In theory, it could be done, but in practice, these are the limitations that we are left to deal with.

Comment: @FrancisCugler Yes, that's what I meant with identifying the template in my comment to your question. As long as the representation of the floating-point number is not specified at least for the compile-time evaluation, it won't be part of the specification.

Answer (score 0):

In modern C++ and how templates are currently designed, I had to slightly restructure my code. It's forcing me to have to use `std::vector` instead of `std::array`, because we can't use `floating-point types` as constant template arguments... So I ended up having to change two of my classes... I had to change my `Limits` class, and my `Function` class.

My `Limits` class now accepts a `Type` instead of `constant-integral-type` and it stores 3 member variables. It also has a default constructor and a user constructor. The functions are now just `constexpr` instead of being static.

My `Function` class now stores a `Limits` class object and `data_points_` is no longer an `std::array` as it is now `std::vector`. It's constructor now also takes in a `Limits` object.

I had also taken into account for the `step` size for `floating-point` ranges.

Here is what my modified code looks like with its given output:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

#include "Function.h"

constexpr int square(int x) {
    return x * x;
}

constexpr int linear(int x) {
    return x;
}

double cosine(double x) {
    return cos(x);
}

//template<float val>
struct foo {
    float operator()(float val) { return val; }
};

int main() {
    try {
        pipes::Functor<int, int> functor1;
        pipes::Limits<int> limit1(-10, 10, 1);
        functor1.FuncPtr = &square;
        pipes::Function<int, int, int> func1( limit1, functor1 );
        auto data1{ func1.data() };
        for (auto& p : data1)
            std::cout << '(' << p.first << ',' << p.second << ")\n";
        std::cout << '\n';
        std::cout << "f(25) = " << func1(25) << "\n\n";

        pipes::Functor<int,int> functor2;
        pipes::Limits<int> limit2(-10, 10, 1);
        functor2.FuncPtr = &linear;
        pipes::Function<int, int, int> func2(limit2, functor2);
        auto data2{ func2.data() };
        for (auto& p : data2)
            std::cout << '(' << p.first << ',' << p.second << ")\n";
        std::cout << '\n';
        std::cout << "f(25) = " << func2(25) << "\n\n";

        constexpr double PI{ 6.28318531 };

        pipes::Functor<double, double> functor3;
        pipes::Limits<double> limits3( (-PI), PI, 0.1);
        functor3.FuncPtr = &cosine;
        pipes::Function<double, double, double> func3(limits3, functor3);
        auto data3{ func3.data() };
        for (auto& p : data3)
            std::cout << '(' << p.first << ',' << p.second << ")\n";
        std::cout << '\n';
        std::cout << "f(25) = " << func3(25) << "\n\n";

    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << "\n\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Function.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>

namespace pipes {

    template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
    struct Functor {
        Ret(*FuncPtr)(Args...);
        Ret operator()(Args... args) { return FuncPtr(args...); }
    };

    template<typename Ty>
    class Limits {
    private:
        Ty Lower;
        Ty Upper;
        Ty Step;

    public:
        Limits() {}
        Limits(Ty lower, Ty upper, Ty step) : Lower{ lower }, Upper{ upper }, Step{ step } {}

        constexpr Ty lower_bound() { return Lower; }
        constexpr Ty upper_bound() { return Upper; }
        constexpr Ty step_size() { return Step; }
        constexpr unsigned element_count() { return (unsigned)((Upper - Lower + 1)/Step); }
    };

    template<typename LimT, typename FuncT, typename... Args>
    class Function {
        Limits<LimT> limits_;
        Functor<FuncT, Args...> functor_;
        std::vector<std::pair<FuncT, FuncT>> data_points_;
    public:
        Function(Limits<LimT> limits, Functor<FuncT,Args...> func) { 
            limits_ = limits;
            functor_ = func;
            data_points_.resize( limits_.element_count() );
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < limits_.element_count(); i++) {
                auto x = limits_.lower_bound() + (i * limits_.step_size());
                data_points_[i].first = (x);
                data_points_[i].second = functor_(x);
            }
        }

        FuncT operator()(Args... args) const { 
            return functor_.FuncPtr(args...);
        }

        constexpr auto lower() const { return limits_.lower_bound(); }
        constexpr auto upper() const { return limits_.upper_bound(); }
        constexpr auto count() const { return limits_.element_count(); }
        constexpr auto step() const { return limits_.step_size(); }
        constexpr auto data() const { return data_points_; }
    };

} // namespace pipes
```

**Output**

```
(-10,100)
(-9,81)
(-8,64)
(-7,49)
(-6,36)
(-5,25)
(-4,16)
(-3,9)
(-2,4)
(-1,1)
(0,0)
(1,1)
(2,4)
(3,9)
(4,16)
(5,25)
(6,36)
(7,49)
(8,64)
(9,81)
(10,100)

f(25) = 625

(-10,-10)
(-9,-9)
(-8,-8)
(-7,-7)
(-6,-6)
(-5,-5)
(-4,-4)
(-3,-3)
(-2,-2)
(-1,-1)
(0,0)
(1,1)
(2,2)
(3,3)
(4,4)
(5,5)
(6,6)
(7,7)
(8,8)
(9,9)
(10,10)

f(25) = 25

(-6.28319,1)
(-6.18319,0.995004)
(-6.08319,0.980067)
(-5.98319,0.955336)
(-5.88319,0.921061)
(-5.78319,0.877583)
(-5.68319,0.825336)
(-5.58319,0.764842)
(-5.48319,0.696707)
(-5.38319,0.62161)
(-5.28319,0.540302)
(-5.18319,0.453596)
(-5.08319,0.362358)
(-4.98319,0.267499)
(-4.88319,0.169967)
(-4.78319,0.0707372)
(-4.68319,-0.0291995)
(-4.58319,-0.128844)
(-4.48319,-0.227202)
(-4.38319,-0.32329)
(-4.28319,-0.416147)
(-4.18319,-0.504846)
(-4.08319,-0.588501)
(-3.98319,-0.666276)
(-3.88319,-0.737394)
(-3.78319,-0.801144)
(-3.68319,-0.856889)
(-3.58319,-0.904072)
(-3.48319,-0.942222)
(-3.38319,-0.970958)
(-3.28319,-0.989992)
(-3.18319,-0.999135)
(-3.08319,-0.998295)
(-2.98319,-0.98748)
(-2.88319,-0.966798)
(-2.78319,-0.936457)
(-2.68319,-0.896758)
(-2.58319,-0.8481)
(-2.48319,-0.790968)
(-2.38319,-0.725932)
(-2.28319,-0.653644)
(-2.18319,-0.574824)
(-2.08319,-0.490261)
(-1.98319,-0.400799)
(-1.88319,-0.307333)
(-1.78319,-0.210796)
(-1.68319,-0.112153)
(-1.58319,-0.0123887)
(-1.48319,0.087499)
(-1.38319,0.186512)
(-1.28319,0.283662)
(-1.18319,0.377978)
(-1.08319,0.468517)
(-0.983185,0.554374)
(-0.883185,0.634693)
(-0.783185,0.70867)
(-0.683185,0.775566)
(-0.583185,0.834713)
(-0.483185,0.88552)
(-0.383185,0.927478)
(-0.283185,0.96017)
(-0.183185,0.983268)
(-0.0831853,0.996542)
(0.0168147,0.999859)
(0.116815,0.993185)
(0.216815,0.976588)
(0.316815,0.950233)
(0.416815,0.914383)
(0.516815,0.869397)
(0.616815,0.815725)
(0.716815,0.753902)
(0.816815,0.684547)
(0.916815,0.608351)
(1.01681,0.526078)
(1.11681,0.438547)
(1.21681,0.346635)
(1.31681,0.25126)
(1.41681,0.153374)
(1.51681,0.0539554)
(1.61681,-0.0460021)
(1.71681,-0.1455)
(1.81681,-0.243544)
(1.91681,-0.339155)
(2.01681,-0.431377)
(2.11681,-0.519289)
(2.21681,-0.602012)
(2.31681,-0.67872)
(2.41681,-0.748647)
(2.51681,-0.811093)
(2.61681,-0.865435)
(2.71681,-0.91113)
(2.81681,-0.947722)
(2.91681,-0.974844)
(3.01681,-0.992225)
(3.11681,-0.999693)
(3.21681,-0.997172)
(3.31681,-0.984688)
(3.41681,-0.962365)
(3.51681,-0.930426)
(3.61681,-0.889191)
(3.71681,-0.839072)
(3.81681,-0.780568)
(3.91681,-0.714266)
(4.01681,-0.640826)
(4.11681,-0.560984)
(4.21681,-0.475537)
(4.31681,-0.385338)
(4.41681,-0.291289)
(4.51681,-0.19433)
(4.61681,-0.0954289)
(4.71681,0.0044257)
(4.81681,0.104236)
(4.91681,0.203005)
(5.01681,0.299745)
(5.11681,0.393491)
(5.21681,0.483305)
(5.31681,0.56829)
(5.41681,0.647596)
(5.51681,0.720432)
(5.61681,0.78607)
(5.71681,0.843854)
(5.81681,0.893206)
(5.91681,0.933634)
(6.01681,0.964733)
(6.11681,0.986192)
(6.21681,0.997798)
(6.31681,0.999435)
(6.41681,0.991085)
(6.51681,0.972833)
(6.61681,0.94486)
(6.71681,0.907447)
(6.81681,0.860967)
(6.91681,0.805884)
(7.01681,0.742749)
(7.11681,0.672193)

f(25) = 0.991203
```

This is giving me the behavior that I want, however, I was trying to do the same thing using `array`... I'm guessing until `C++` supports `floating-point-constants` as template arguments I'm going to have to settle with `std::vector` using heap allocations, instead of `std::array` and stack-cache friendly containers...